# Uncaught TypeError: $(…).multiselect is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm trying to use the multi select plugin (http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

I get the folllowing error: $(...).multiselect is not a function

and I can't figure out how to make it work...

```
<!-- Include Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery: -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Here is my select:

```
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="0">value0</option>
    <option value="1">value1</option>
    <option value="2">value2</option>
    <option value="3">value3</option>
</select>
```

And then I call the plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.multiselect').multiselect();
    });
</script>
```

I've tried to call the plugin where I link the css and js, but it still won't work.

Comment: Is the path for the multi select js file correct? If so, are you having other JS errors?

Comment: Is that the only error you see in the console? I have used that plugin many times and never had a problem

Comment: If i look at chrome's console it doesnt any other errors and I reviewed my paths multiple times already. I guess I can take another look ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake!

I was linking another jquery.min.js further in my code. Now it works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with ASP.Net check the follow. If the Master Page has JS or CSS in your aspx don't put them again, 'cause the aspx Inherits from the Master Page. Just put the missing ones.